# freeswitch configuration for ipkall

Tags: freeswitch

i have setup my freeswitch with plivo but now i m unable to configure ipkall number for my sip user 1005@ipadress since the configuration of freeswitch wiki for ipkall is not clear.
Please can anybody give me steps to configure?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes i have found the answere for this one if anybody is facing problem regarding this just needed to copy the wiki config into external_profiles in freeswitch. after that it was a different scenario since this can be used by using a pstn number which i got from ipkall then was able to connect to this user and remember i never change default configuration in dialplan.

Answer (score 0):

in dialplan/public.xml (or an included file):

```
<include>
  <extension name="IPKALL">
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^5150$">
      <action application="set" data="domain_name=freeswitch.org"/>
      <action application="transfer" data="1001 XML default"/>
    </condition>
  </extension>
</include>
```